# Infinite loop in useEffect when setting state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a question about `useEffect` and `useState` inside of it. 
I am building a component:

```
const [id, setId] = useState(0);
const [currencies, setCurrencies] = useState([]);

...
useEffect(()=> {
const getCurrentCurrency = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP`);
            const data = await response.json();
            const currencyArray = [];
            const {EUR:euro ,CHF:franc, USD: dolar} = data.rates;
            currencyArray.push(euro, dolar/franc,1/dolar);
            console.log("currencyArray", currencyArray);
             setCurrencies(currencies => [...currencies, currencyArray]);
          }
          getCurrentCurrency();
    }, [id, currencies.length]);
```

Which is used for making a new API request when only id change. I need to every time that ID change make a new request with new data. In my case now I have infinite loop. I try to use dependencies but it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: why do you need `currencies.length1` if you only want to update when ID change

Comment: even if have only id dependency there is infinite loop. I change the state inside useEffect so this is the cause but I don't know how to workaround it in dependency. I try to use multiple dependencies ( this is why i add `currencies.length`) but it doesn't work

Comment: first line of my snippet.

Comment: where does `id` come from?

Comment: `const [id, setId] = useState(0);` and then  i change it somewhere in the handler for go between the slides in slider like this:  `const goToPrevSlide = () => {
        id === 0 ? setId(2) : setId(id-1);
    }
    const goToNextSlide = () =>{
        id === 2 ? setId(0) : setId(id+1);
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changing a value (`currencies.length`), which the `useEffect` depends on (`[id, currencies.length]`), on every call.

Therefore you cause an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getCurrentCurrency = async () => {
    // ...
    currencyArray.push(euro, dolar / franc, 1 / dolar);

//                    v The length is changed on every call
    setCurrencies(currencies => [...currencies, currencyArray]);
  };
  getCurrentCurrency();
//                    v Will called on every length change
}, [id,currencies.length]);
```

---

You don't need `currencies.length` as a dependency when you using a functional `useState`, `currencies => [...currencies, currencyArray]`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getCurrentCurrency = async () => {
    ...
  }
  getCurrentCurrency();

}, [id]);
```

---

Moreover, as it seems an exchange application, you might one to use an interval for fetching the currency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(getCurrency, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: Ok but why this is not working if i have only one dependency (id). My logic is described here: 1. When I mount component I would like to update default current state with currencies. 2. when i click button which change my id state i want to make new API request (by useEffect) and then I invoke my state  once again with updated currencies from API.

Comment: Thats should work, just be sure on changing the id its different from the previous value

Comment: Working only if I update state directrly by using: `currencies.push(euro, dolar/franc,1/dolar);` not by `setCurrencies(currencies => [...currencies, currencyArray]);`

Answer (score 0):

you can just call the `useEffect` `cb` one the component mounted:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
 //your code
 // no need for checking for the updates it they are inside the component
 }, []);
```